# Get current news for a location

Tags: ios, web-services, geospatial, feed

Is it possible in an iOS application to get current news for a particular location ? Is there some api available where I can pass location as parameter and get news for that location ?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by location. You want country? city?, distance within 1 KM ?, etc.. please explain that a bit more

Comment: @MostafaTorbjørnBerg : Location is any place on globe city/ town but now country or a state.

Comment: http://google.com/search?q=local+news+api

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For local news in the US, you can use the Patch api, it allows you to get news for a zip code, state, or even down to a neighbourhood.

here are some examples from their API page:

**News for a zip code**

`http://news-api.patch.com/v1.1/zipcodes/{ZIP}/stories?dev_key={key}&sig={signature}`

**News for a state**

`http://news-api.patch.com/v1.1/states/{state name}/stories?dev_key={key}&sig={signature}`

**News for a City**

`http://news-api.patch.com/v1.0/states/ca/cities/san%20francisco/stories?dev_key={key}&sig={signature}`

**News using GPS coordinates**

`http://news-api.patch.com/v1.1/nearby/{latitude},{longitude}/stories?dev_key={key}&sig={signature}`

Response will contain lots of metadata, a title, a story, attachments, and even GPS coordinates of the location of the news items returned, with tons of other features

Now the down side this is US only, there are many other APIs out there that you can use for different countries, [here's the BBC API](http://api.bbcnews.appengine.co.uk) for example **Update:This is down now**

You can grab news data from places, like this call
http://api.bbcnews.appengine.co.uk/stories/uk
**Update: This is also down**. You may use [their RSS feeds](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/10628494) instead.

Also CNN has it's [news RSS feed](http://edition.cnn.com/services/rss/) 
Where you can fetch RSS data about news in many locations

- World
- Africa
- Americas
- Asia
- Europe
- Middle East
- U.S.

I'm pretty sure there are tons of other APIs out there, one of my favorites is the [Ushahidi network](http://www.ushahidi.com)

They have a public API that also has location tags for news items, you can learn more [here](https://wiki.ushahidi.com/display/WIKI/Ushahidi+Public+API)

I think this is quite enough to get you started and to show you the possibilities of open APIs, if you need more details please let me know, I'm pretty sure there's more out there if you search right !

Answer (score 6):

Depending on your needs, you want to use  **Google News API** their section feeds, their search feeds
[google news](http://support.google.com/news/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=59255)

[Google news rss](http://news.google.com/news?q=apple&output=rss)

or Bing News Search.

[Bing developer](http://www.bing.com/toolbox/bingdeveloper/)

Answer (score 2):

Either when you are using a API like Google News or the one from Patch, or any other. Most don't accept GPS locations for the search. They need a qualified zip code or city name or other human readable location data.

To figure out the address where the user currently is, you need the [CLGeocoder](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/Reference/Reference.html) to reverse lookup the address for a given GPS coordinate.
This can be done like this:

```
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geoCoder reverseGeocodeLocation:cllocationToSearchForNews completionHandler: 
     ^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

         //Get nearby address
         CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];

         //post of the placemark
         NSString *postalCode = placemark.postalCode;

         //String to hold address
         NSString *locatedAt = [[placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"] componentsJoinedByString:@", "];


     }];
```

With the [CLPlacemark](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLPlacemark_class/Reference/Reference.html) figured out from the GPS Location you can have nearly every address information from it:
name  property

- addressDictionary
- ISOcountryCode
- country
- postalCode
- administrativeArea
- subAdministrativeArea
- locality
- subLocality
- thoroughfare
- subThoroughfare
- region

With this informations you can query nearly every news api. Also the one from patch mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17097920/1578508) by [mostafa torbjorn berg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/609099/mostafa-torbjorn-berg)
News for a zip code

```
http://news-api.patch.com/v1.1/zipcodes/{ZIP}/stories?dev_key={key}&sig={signature}
```

News for a state

```
http://news-api.patch.com/v1.1/states/{state name}/stories?dev_key={key}&sig={signature}
```

News for a City

```
http://news-api.patch.com/v1.0/states/ca/cities/san%20francisco/stories?dev_key={key}&sig={signature}
```

News using GPS coordinates

```
http://news-api.patch.com/v1.1/nearby/{latitude},{longitude}/stories?dev_key={key}&sig={signature}
```

Answer (score 0):

First get your current GPS coordinates. Then use reverse-geocoding of the [CLGeocoder Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CLGeocoder) to turn the coordinates into a street address.

Once you have a working street address, you can use any number of news feeds or news APIs (too many to list) based on your city/town.